# Complex SQL query, not sure where to start

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a tough one here I think. I have the following tables:

```
[Assets]
AssetId | Name              
1       | Acura NSX
2       | Dodge Ram

[Assignments]
AssignmentId | AssetId | StartMileage | EndMileage | StartDate | EndDate
1            | 1       | 8000         | 10000      | 4/1/2015  | 5/1/2015
2            | 1       | 10000        | 16000      | 9/15/2015 | 1/5/2016
3            | 2       | 51000        | NULL       | 1/1/2016  | NULL

[Reminders]
ReminderId | AssetId | Name          | Distance    | Time      | Active
1          | 1       | Oil Change    | 3000 (miles)| 3 (months)| 1
2          | 1       | Tire Rotation | 5000        | 6         | 0
3          | 2       | Oil Change    | 3000        | 3         | 1
4          | 2       | Air Filter    | 50000       | 48        | 1

[Maintenance]
MaintenanceId | AssetId | ReminderId | Mileage   | Date     | Vendor
1             | 1       | 1          | 10000     | 5/1/2015 | Jiffy Lube
2             | 2       | 3          | 51000     | 6/1/2015 | Dealership
```

I need a query that will join these 4 tables and return something like the following.

```
Name      | Name          | Current Mileage | Last Mileage | Last Date
Acura NSX | Oil Change    | 16000           | 10000        | 5/1/2015
Dodge RAM | Oil Change    | 51000           | 51000        | 6/1/2015
Dodge RAM | Air Filter    | 51000           | --           | --
```

I need to take the distance threshold from the Reminders table and add it to the mileage from the Maintenance table then compare it to the start and end mileage from the Assignments table. If the threshold is greater than the start or end mileage then select the asset name, the name of the reminder, the current mileage (start or end mileage from Assignments, whichever is greater), and mileage and date from the last maintenance for that reminder. I need to do the same for time threshold. Add it to the date from the Maintenance table then compare it to today's date. If it's greater then display the asset.

Can one of you SQL gurus help me with this please?

UPDATE:

```
SELECT
    v.Name,
    r.Name AS Reminder,
    a.CurrentMileage,
    i.MaintenanceMileage,
    i.MaintenanceDate
FROM
    Assets v
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT AssetId,
            COALESCE(EndMileage, StartMileage) AS CurrentMileage,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AssetId
                               ORDER BY AssignmentId DESC) AS window_id
    FROM Assignments) a
    ON v.AssetId = a.AssetId
    AND a.window_id = 1
JOIN
    Reminders r
    ON v.AssetId = r.AssetId
    AND r.ActiveFlag = 1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT AssetId,
            ReminderId,
            MAX(Mileage) AS MaintenanceMileage,
            MAX([Date]) AS MaintenanceDate
    FROM Maintenances
    GROUP BY AssetId, ReminderId) i
    ON r.ReminderId = i.ReminderId
    AND (a.CurrentMileage > (NULLIF(i.MaintenanceMileage, 0) + r.DistanceThreshold))
    OR (GETDATE() > DATEADD(m, r.[TimeThreshold], i.MaintenanceDate))
```

Comment: There are multiple Assignments for an Asset. How do you pick which Assignment row to use?

Comment: You would use the latest assignment by either AssignmentId or StartDate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a starting point:

```
SELECT v.Name AS [Asset Name], r.Name AS Reminder, a.CurrentMileage,
        m.Mileage + r.Distance AS [Last Mileage], m.[Date] AS [Last Date]
    FROM Assets v
    JOIN ( -- get the latest relevant row as window_id = 1
            SELECT AssetId, COALESCE(EndMileage, StartMileage) AS CurrentMileage,
                    COALESCE(EndDate, StartDate) AS AssignDate,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by AssetId
                                        order by COALESCE(EndDate, StartDate) DESC) AS window_id
                FROM Assignments
    ) a
        ON v.AssetId = a.AssetId
        AND a.window_id = 1
    JOIN Reminders r
        ON v.AssetId = r.AssetId
        AND r.Active = 1
    LEFT JOIN Maintenance m
        ON r.AssetId = m.AssetId
        AND r.ReminderId = m.ReminderId
                    -- corrected
            AND ((a.CurrentMileage > (NULLIF(m.Mileage, 0) + r.Distance))
            -- slightly oversimplified
            OR (GETDATE() > DATEADD(m, r.[Time], COALESCE(m.[Date], a.AssignDate))))
```

The date calculations are slightly oversimplified because they use the latest assignment dates. What you would really want is a column `Assets.InServiceDate` that would anchor the time before the first maintenance would be due. But this will get you started.

Comment: The first part of the WHERE clause checks that the current mileage is greater than the last maintenance mileage plus the distance interval from [Reminders]. You can modify that to blend in your rules. This is a starting point.

Comment: That is the purpose of the LEFT JOIN to [Maintenance]. If there is no row for [Maintenance], then the values of the columns will be NULL, so `NULLIF(m.Mileage, 0)` says that, if there has been no maintenance, use zero for the mileage at which the maintenance was done.

Comment: I just corrected the query. The problem was that I had constraints in the WHERE clause depending on the optional relationship to [Maintenance], which undoes the optionality of the LEFT JOIN. I moved them to the LEFT JOIN and now it works.

Comment: Thanks. I just found something else that I haven't been able to fix. As soon as I add a row in the maintenance table for a different asset, i.e. Dodge RAM, I get a duplicate row in the query. The duplicate row has the maintenance.assetid from the other asset but v.assetid, a.assetid,  and r.assetid are correct. I think it's because there are no rows in the assignments and mantenance tables for that asset because it's new (which is possible) but I can't fix it. I thought joining on v.assetid on LEFT JOIN Maintenances m instead of r.assetid might work but it didn't.

Comment: In [Maintenance], the combo (AssetId, ReminderId) has to be unique or that could happen. Actually, since you can use ReminderId to uniquely identify the [Assets] row, you don't need AssetId at all in [Maintenance]. This gets into database design, which is a different topic.

Comment: Maintenance.AssetId is used else where which is why it's there. I do have unique combo (AssetId, ReminderId) in Maintenance (2,1) and (7,8) but I do need to have multiple as it keeps a history of the maintenance done on the asset.

Comment: Then you're going to need a subselect with a window_id on [Maintenance] similar to the one on [Assignments].

Comment: After further review, if all you need from [Maintenance] is `AssetId, ReminderId, MAX(Mileage), MAX([Date])`, you could get away with a subquery with `GROUP BY AssetId, ReminderId`. But you would have to have a subquery.

Comment: I added the query I'm using above. It appears the cause of that duplicate row with the wrong maintenance.assetid is from the last line of the query: OR (GETDATE() > DATEADD(m, r.[TimeThreshold], COALESCE(i.MaintenanceDate, a.AssignDate))). Is there a way to address this or do I need to add the Assets.InServiceDate? Thanks Rojak.

Comment: It goes back to the requirements for which you want to model data.Does the assignment date have any influence over when the vehicle needs next maintenance? For example, does the Acura need to have oil changed every three months? Does it need to have oil changed after three months of being assigned (that would require you to total time having been assigned)? Does it need to have oil changed three months after having been assigned for the first time or for the first time after having had the oil changed? The rules govern how the data comes together.

Comment: For the time threshold from reminder, only Maintenance.Date should matter because I'm only concerned with when that particular maintenance was last performed. The idea is to check for the single greatest mileage for each asset from assignments and maintenance and see if it has been exceeded and check date from maintenance and see if it has been exceed. If either has been exceeded then select.

Comment: Then you have an issue with the first maintenance: if the maintenance in question has never been performed, what do you compare the date to? That is why I suggested an in-service date.